Не работает поиск и выбор категорий товаров WooCommerce в виджете Elementor
Я импортировал 47 000 продуктов WooCommerce на свой сайт. Вместе с этим я импортировал 300 категорий и 7000 атрибутов товаров. Это был парсинг с другого сайта.
К сожалению, все названия товаров, категорий и атрибутов были больше 28 символов, и мне пришлось добавить код в файл functions.php, чтобы импорт не выдавал постоянных ошибок.
add_filter('sanitize_taxonomy_name', function( $urldecode, $taxonomy ) {
$urldecode = mb_substr($urldecode, 0, 27, 'utf-8');
return $urldecode;
}, 10, 2 );

В файле wc-attribute-functions.php на время импорта, мне пришлось исправить валидацию slug.
// Validate slug.
if ( strlen( $slug ) > 200 ) {

Импорт прошел нормально, но затем возникла новая проблема. Я использую Elementor и тему Woodmart. В виджете «Сетка и карусель товаров» перестал работать поиск и выбор категорий товаров. Выдается результат «Поиск не найден», хотя до этого все работало.
Оказалось, что если удалить все товары, категории и атрибуты, то поиск категорий в виджете снова начинает работать корректно.
Может ли это быть связано с большим количеством символов slug? Просто переименовать в общей сложности более 50 000 slug - не вариант.
Может быть, кто-то сталкивался с этой проблемой и знает, как ее решить? Буду рад вашей помощи!

Может ли это быть связано с большим количеством символов slug? -- там на уровне БД есть ограничение varchar(200), потому slug длиннее 200 символов Вы туда все равно не запишете

Это я понимаю. Но почему только удаление всех товаров, категорий, атрибутов и создание тестовых не больше 28 знаков, возвращает корректную работу поиска в виджете? И как это можно исправить?
